# Installing program on ubuntu pen drive

Tags: 12.10, usb-drive, xubuntu

I have installed Ubuntu in my pen drive & I use my pen drive as my computer & I install some application on this Ubuntu but when ever restarted my Ubuntu operating system my installed applications were removed.
Please...! Can any buddy tell me how can I save the applications which are installed on my Ubuntu pen-drive...?

Comment: Are you using a LiveCD or LiveUSB?

Answer (score 0):

When you created the pen drive install did you give yourself space for persistence? Its an option to allocate additional space when creating the drive to allow room for additional applications and files. 
Using Ubuntu's *USB startup creator* this option is called **Stored in reserve extra space** 
If you used *unetbootin* it is referred to as **space used to reserve file access across reboots**.

If you did not choose to allow additional space then it will not save any changes after a reboot.